# Can not replace the content of a csv file in Go

Tags: go

I have created a csv file (assume "output.csv") using `os.OpenFile` with flags, `os.Create` and `os.RDWR`. I'm doing a series of operations on this file. In every Iteration, I need to rewrite the contents of the csv file ("output.csv"). But My code appends to the csv file.

Comment: What's your question? Give an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (i.e. what have you tried, what do you get, what do you want). Without that people would only be guessing (my guess is that you might want [`Seek`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Seek) and [`Truncate`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Truncate).

Answer (score 3):

Before each *rewrite*, truncate the file and seek to the beginning.
Example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    if f, err := os.Create("test.csv"); err == nil {
        defer f.Close()
        for n := 10; n > 0; n-- {
            f.Truncate(0) // comment or uncomment
            f.Seek(0, 0)  // these lines to see the difference
            for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
                f.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("%d\n", i))
            }
        }
    } else {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

opening file in read and write(os.RDWR) mode appends to the file.

Sol:
open the file in read only mode(**os.RDONLY**) for reading and close it after reading.

```
csvfile ,_:= os.OpenFile("output.csv", os.O_RDONLY|os.O_CREATE, 0777)
csvfile.Close()
```

For writing, open the file in write only mode(**os.WRONLY**) and close it after writing, this overwrites the file rather than appending.

```
csvfile ,_:= os.OpenFile("output.csv", os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE, 0777)
csvfile.Close()
```

for appending you could use **os.APPEND**

Comment: How do you know os.RD_WR appends to the file rather than just overwriting it? That doesn't sound right.